# Спасибо и пожалуйста

Tags: этикет

Сейчас в супермаркетах часто слышу, как вручая  товар продавец говорит - "Спасибо", что мне видится несколько неестественным. В связи с этим возник вопрос: Когда дают говорят пожалуйста, берут - спасибо, а если меняются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему неестественно? Он благодарит Вас за то, что Вы купили именно у него и принесли ему прибыль. Вы в ответ тоже можете сказать "спасибо" за то, что он оказал услугу и продал нужный товар. Будем взаимно вежливы! "Пожалуйста" в его устах тоже будет звучать вежливо, но это будет признанием того, что он оказал услугу,а не ему. Современный этикет в торговле при большой конкуренции требует признания того, чтобы покупатель чувствовал себя хозяином положения, ведь он может выбрать другой магазин и оказать услугу другому торговому предприятию. Это борьба за покупателя.

Comment: Неестественно потому, что говорят так когда передают сдачу и покупку, а не когда берут деньги. Получается, что они мне благодарны за то, что вручают мне товар. Без "за  покупку" получается именно так. Я бы при прочих равных предпочёл бы магазин, где не пришлось бы гадать за что меня блогодарят.

Comment: Это же устный диалог, реплики коротки, просто "за покупку" подразумевается, это сейчас всем привычно - современное требование профессиональной этики в торговле.В простой обстановке, не в ситуации торговли,да, мы говорим :"Возьмите, пожалуйста", а данная ситуация - обстановка профессионального общения, а не бытового, здесь и вежливость профессиональная:"Спасибо за покупку" - "Спасибо за услугу, товар".

Comment: В одном магазине, куда я часто заглядываю, кассиры заученно произносят : *Спасибо за покупку, приходите к нам еще!*

Вот уже два года так говорят, пока не сокращают)

Comment: Ну да,их этому учат и это требуют, но можно говорить "заученно", а можно от души, по-человечески, тогда мы только ради открытой улыбки в этот магазин ходить будем - это тоже профессионализм, чего у нас так мало.

Answer (score 2):

Продавец имеет в виду "Спасибо за покупку". Дают-берут не принципиально. В ответ лучше всего тоже сказать "спасибо".

Answer (score 1):

Насчет этикетных представлений Вам ответили. Я присоединяюсь.  
Попробую немного разбавить филологией.

Спасибо происходит от "спаси (тебя) бог". Круг ситуаций, в которых можно употребить этот оборот, сами понимаете, был весьма широк. С упрощением формулы он не только не сузился, но и даже расширился. Ситуация со "спасибо за покупку" да и просто со вручением чего-либо вполне в этот круг вписывается.

С "пожалуйста" ситуация в общем-то похожа. Оно означало "пожалуй, старый" ("старый" - эквивалент современного "уважаемый") и употреблялось в качестве достаточно универсальной формулы для привлечения внимания, особо вежливой просьбы, в ответ на благодарность. В таком употреблении и сохранилось, несколько даже расширив   употребительность.

Так что ничего неестественного не будет даже в диалоге типа 
 - "Возьми, спасибо"
 - "Взял, пожалуйста".

Если, скажем, долг отдают.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, так пусть лучше заученно говорят "спасибо" и "пожалуйста", чем хамят.